# Spray REST WebService Application

Tags: actor, spray

I'm using Spray for exposing a set of RESTful services. In one of the service, I have to make a call to another REST end point. For this purpose, I'm using Play framework's WSClient (from the play.api.libs.ws.{WS, WSClient}). I can see from my logs that when I use Play's WSClient, I get another ActorSystem initialised. Two questions:

1. How could I make use of the underlying Spray's Actor System (the one that I create when I start my application)
2. Is there a Spray library that I could use instead of Play's?

Comment: You can do everything described using akka-http. It's successor of Spray. http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/2.0.3/scala/http/index.html

Comment: Yes, there is `spray-client`